# Failed to Build AppBundle

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to build appbundle using command flutter build appbundle. However, it will not start because of the following error:

```
Failed to open output file 'F:\Mobile app\user app\booking_system_flutter\booking_system_flutter\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release\flutter_asse
    ts\packages/flutter_vector_icons/fonts/AntDesign.ttf'. The parent directory may not exist, or the user does not have permission to create this file.
    
    Failed to open output file 'F:\Mobile app\user app\booking_system_flutter\booking_system_flutter\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release\flutter_asse
    ts\packages/flutter_vector_icons/fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'. The parent directory may not exist, or the user does not have permission to create this file.
    
    Failed to open output file 'F:\Mobile app\user app\booking_system_flutter\booking_system_flutter\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release\flutter_asse
    ts\fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf'. The parent directory may not exist, or the user does not have permission to create this file.
```

Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have permission conflict in your directories or specific type of files (like ttf maybe).

If you using IDE or Code Editor terminal just open it with **run as administrator** or just open your platform terminal with **as administrator** it will help.

In my case I use vs code
[image: Run vs code as administrator]

Or cmd as terminal
[image: Run cmd as Administrator]

if you are storing project in usb or other drives, just copy and paste in your locale drive and there won't be similar problem.

Comment: i dont get it, how to do that btw? there is no option to run as admin in AS terminal i think

Comment: @MuhammadRoyyan I have edited my answer with more info.